# Div tag Scrolling to bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I have gone through all related questions. But didn't find any answer.
My question is i have scrollable div tag, a chat window, in which images can be dropped as well. I have span tag at the end of every message so using this code the div tag scrolls properly to the bottom.

```
var EndChat = $(myid);
var chat_target = EndChat.find('span').last();
EndChat.scrollTo(chat_target, 1000);
```

But When i append Image after resizing it, It doesn't get to the bottom. It stop at 1/4th of the image.

And when the chat loads in the beginning, if there are many images, the scrolling stops even more far from the bottom. Please Help

Comment: Is it possible that it tries scrolling before the image is completely loaded?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am doing it after the Image is appended.

Comment: appending the image and loading are two different things - you'll append it to the DOM and it'll start to load, but it doesn't take it's final dimensions until the http request completes and the image displays, THEN it will take it's final shape and cause content to move down, which is why you're getting it at about 1/4th of the image; it's finishing scrolling before the image is loaded.

Comment: Oh, i see. Is there anything i can do to correct it?

Comment: I'll make a legit answer

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you scroll to the bottom of the chat using:

```
EndChat.scrollTop(EndChat[0].scrollHeight);
```

It works: http://jsfiddle.net/shawn31313/mb6JA/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried it, it doesn't work. I checked the same code in IE 10 and it seems to work fine. I just don't know what is wrong with Chrome.

Comment: @Chandroid Did you check the example? It seems to be working in chrome for me.

Comment: Yes. I did. It works when you try with the console. But when i use it in the application it doesn't work. But it does work with IE.

Comment: @Chandroid Does it scroll to the bottom at all?

Comment: In IE, Yes. But not in Chrome.

Comment: So, in Chrome it doesn't scroll at all? It stays on top? ... if so then you can try to be a bug fixer and `console.log(EndChat[0].scrollHeight)` and see what you get in chrome. Please note that the above code should not be in an `onload` function such as `$(window).load(function { .. })`

Comment: It works and i get some Number. But still it stop at half height of the scroll. But if the scrollbar doesn't have any images, it scrolls to the bottom without any problem.

Comment: Oh, in that case, you should add the function in `$(window).load(function { .. })`..this will wait for the images to load and it should work better.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make sure the images have loaded before scrolling, attach an event to the load, something like this:

```
$('.chat img').on('load', function() {
    var chat_target = EndChat.find('span').last();
    EndChat.scrollTo(chat_target, 1000);
});
```

If I'm not mistaken, whenever an image in `.chat` is loaded, it'll trigger the scroll to the footer. You could modify it as necessary :)